# SQL Statement running Slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, loading, statements

I am having problems loading data from a log table. I'm trying to filter the table on a column that has a string. Below is the statement I'm using. I can pull data up to 4 weeks previously, but when i try to pull in more historic data it times out. I hav eextended the time out to 600 seconds, but stil the same mistake. So I presume there is a better way of wriing my statement?

In addition if possible I would like to have the most recent timestamp based on the value

Thanking you in advance.
Joe

```
select 
dl.user_id, 
dl.timestamp,
dl.value,
dl.operation,
concat(concat(un.first_name, ' '), un.last_name) AS "User" ,
from data_log dl 
where  dl.timestamp >= date '2019-12-01' and dl.operation = 'update' and dl.values like 
'%"date_time"%'
```

Comment: How many rows are we talking?

Comment: What indices do you have?

Comment: Also, what do you expect the like to match (i.e. what is the form of dl.values)?

Comment: What is the type of `dl.values` ?

Comment: Questions about query performance always require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables as well as the EXPLAIN for the given query. Also, note that `like '%...'` cannot use an index

Comment: use explain to see what the sql parser will do, most times it help to crerate a index over some of your colums. it would also good to see your create table statment to see which index you have created

Comment: a [Full-text search index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) can help

Comment: The LIKE operation is slow. You can use DATE_FORMAT function with equal statement instead. Please provide dl.values and  'date_time' examples

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
select dl.user_id, dl.timestamp, dl.value, dl.operation,
       concat(concat(un.first_name, ' '),
       un.last_name) AS "User"
from data_log dl 
where dl.timestamp >= date '2019-12-01' and
      dl.operation = 'update' and
      dl.values like '%"date_time"%';
```

You want an index on `data_log(operation, timestamp, values)`.  This *might* help the performance issue.